# Unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site; profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I can't seem to access my profile page on any SE site. I've tried Stack Overflow, Parenting, Workplace and Code Review.

This is what I see:

[image: enter code here]

After further investigation this does seem pretty random. I am also getting the error in the following places:

- [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) main page, main profile page and Meta profile page
- [Workplace Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/) page as well as profile page

My profile page for MSE is OK as is my Meta profile for Stack Overflow from what I can tell.

Comment: What's unclear about "We're working on it"?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: it's a standard message, and we are seeing more users reporting this on SO. A widespread main page outage for a subset of users is worth reporting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, I see. Mine's working fine BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yup, mine is too, which is why it is either an issue with specific profiles or a CDN node.

Comment: Happening in Australia. Doesn't happen if I'm not logged in.

Comment: This is probably not related to location, but rather with your profile, because multiple locations report the issue, some people in the same geographic locations don't see it, and people don't see it when logged out.So not necessarily related to location, but with your profile, because multiple locations report the issue, some people in the same geographic locations don't see it, and people don't see it when logged out.

Comment: Same question on stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349741/main-site-seems-to-be-down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We threw 10,230 errors here (network-wide) due to a web server exhausting memory (due to another, competing application pool being a bully). I posted some details [over on Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349749/13249).

This means the day can only get better, right??